# Как собрать в массив url(ы) нужных страниц?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть такой парсер, он уже работает НО:

Сейчас ссылки на страницы которые парсятся подставляются вручную, мне же нужно собрать сначала нужные ссылки в массив, при том что я не знаю сколько их, какая у них вложеность и т.д, я знаю только url сайта с которого мне нужно парсить статьи

```js
const tress = require('tress');
const needle = require("needle");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const async = require("async");
const fs = require('fs');

let aUrl = [
    // Здесь нужно написать цикл который будет собирать все url в массив
    'ссылка на товар',
    'ссылка на товар',
    'ссылка на товар',
];

const jquery = body => cheerio.load(body);

let products = [];

let parsePage = ($) => {
    let name = $("#shop-production-view > h1").first().text();
    let categories = $(".breadcrumb").text();
    let price = $(".price").text();
    let content = $('.content_item').html();
    let images = $(".image").find("img").attr("src");

    // let $imageLink = $(".shop-production-view .image a"),
    //     img = '';
    // if ($imageLink.length > 0) {
    //     img = $imageLink.attr("href");
    // }


    products.push({
        name,
        categories,
        content,
        price,
        images,
        // img,
    });
};

let q = tress((url, callback) => {
    needle.get(url, {  }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        parsePage(jquery(res.body));

        callback();
    });
}, 5);

q.drain = () => {
    console.log(products);
};

for (let i = 0; i < aUrl.length; i++) {
    q.push(aUrl[i]);
}
```

Comment: Соответственно нужно дописать скрипт, который сначала на одной странице соберет ссылки товаров в массив, а потом уже запускать текущий, который распарсит каждый товар.

Comment: @АртемНиколаев ну вот я и просил помочь с написанием